# Pyflakes with Emacs

Tags: python, emacs, static-analysis, flymake, pyflakes

I'm trying to install pyflakes with emacs. So far, i've got the flymake.el file from [here](http://cvs.savannah.gnu.org/viewvc/emacs/emacs/lisp/progmodes/flymake.el). I put it inside my .emacs.d folder. Inside my .emacs file, I have this:

```
(when (load "flymake" t)
  (defun flymake-pyflakes-init ()
    (let* ((temp-file (flymake-init-create-temp-buffer-copy
                       'flymake-create-temp-inplace))
           (local-file (file-relative-name
                        temp-file
                           (file-name-directory buffer-file-name))))
  (list "pyflakes" (list local-file))))

  (add-to-list 'flymake-allowed-file-name-masks
               '("\\.py\\'" flymake-pyflakes-init)))

(add-hook 'find-file-hook 'flymake-find-file-hook)
```

I've also downloaded pyflakes and it's callable from the command line. However, when I open up my emacs with a file, I still get that it cannot find the program 'pyflakes'. Why can't emacs find pyflakes while my command line can? I'm on iOS.

Comment: You are running Emacs on iOS?!  And btw, Flymake is shipped with Emacs, so you've "installed" a file that is already part of Emacs.  You are likely even using the builtin version, because `emacs.d` is normally not in the `load-path`.  Concerning the problem, inspect the contents of your `exec-path` in your Emacs, and check whether it contains the directory with the pyflakes executable.

Comment: I got it! I added the bin directory where pyflakes was by doing (add-to-list 'exec-path *path-here*)

Answer (score 0):

Add `/path/to/python/scripts` in emacs's `exec-path`, by either adding the following line to  *init.el* or <kbd>M-:</kbd>

```
(setq exec-path (cons /path/to/python/scripts exec-path))
```